# How to make a hover effect with border lines

Tags: html, css

I want to reproduce the same hover effect of the picture attached [image]

This a sketch and I'm not very sure how to start

Comment: try with css pseudo-elements

Comment: A good place to start when faced with a problem like this, is to consult google. StackOverflow is a fantastic resource when trying to solve a bug in your code, but it's generally good to try and search for 'hover button tutorial' etc first. You'll learn faster and feel like you've achieved something when you read a guide and produce a result yourself. If you get stuck, of course, you can share your code and we can help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution: http://codepen.io/thovo/pen/WxQpaP

The idea is you can not use either `border-bottom` or `box-shadow` for the main `li` that contain `a`, so I recommend to go with peuseudo class like `before` or `after` to get the same effect in your picture.

**EDIT1** I just borrowed the HTML part from @Jacob

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to show a thick line below each item when you hover, there are multiple ways you can do it.

**EDIT :** I added a few more solutions using `background-position` and `linear-gradient`.

## `border`

### Set to display a border when you hover an `li` item.

This has problems because bringing in a border will force the element to move and break the alignment. In this particular case, the text content would move up. (Example - 1).

### Just set border-color on hover.

What you do is set border for all `li` items from start with `transparent` as the border color. When you hover over each item, you just change the color to the desired color. This way it doesn't break your layout. (Example - 2).

## `box-shadow`

`box-shadow` can be used to trick this and it's better than `border` approach because it doesn't affect the box model of the element. (Example - 3).

```css
.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  padding: 10px;
}
.menu.border li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid tomato;
  /*causes disturbances in layout*/
}
.menu.border-better li {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  /* forces you to have borders from start and consider them in calculation of height*/
}
.menu.border-better li:hover {
  border-bottom-color: goldenrod;
}
.menu.box-shadow li:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 magenta;
}
.menu.gradient li:hover {
  /*If you don't care about transition...
  * also, it may not work in multiple scenarios.
  */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, red 2px, transparent 0);
}
.menu.background-position li {
  /** want to use background but want transition to work? use this.*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, red 2px, transparent 0);
  background-position: 0 2px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.menu.background-position li:hover {
  background-position: initial;
}
```

```html
Example - 1
<ul class="menu border">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>

Example - 2
<ul class="menu border-better">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
Example - 3
<ul class="menu box-shadow">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
Example - 4
<ul class="menu gradient">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>

Example - 5
<ul class="menu background-position">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

I personally prefer the `box-shadow` approach because.

- It has great browser support.
- It doesn't disturb other elements on the page.
- It doesn't require me to start with some sort of set up.
- It doesn't affect the box model of the element in question.

Comment: your answer didn't fullfill the requirement of the pictures

Comment: A picture can't depict how a hover effect may look like. I have assumed stuff based on the picture and coded solutions. I'll mention that. Thanks.

Comment: well, if you work with a designer, she will fail you for the first attempt :)

Comment: I knew there was something making it weird for me to work with designers ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would accomplish this by replacing something like a `margin-bottom` and replacing it with a `border-bottom`, like:

```
nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

nav a:hover {
    margin-bottom: none;
    border-bottom: 4px;
}
```

This is assuming your HTML is something like:

```
<nav>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Schools</a>
    <a href="#">Jobs</a>
    <a href="#">Lookbook</a>
    <a href="#">Figures</a>
    <a href="#">Indexes</a>
    <a href="#">Calendars</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Note, you can pad the bottom of the ``p`` element and then apply a ``border-bottom``.

Comment: Hm, not sure how styling `p` elements would affect the anchors here.

Comment: if you don't mind, may I use your html code for my answer?

Comment: Oops, may have missed the chance but sure thing! Clever call on `box-shadow` and `background-position`; I love them. In the near future I'll probably be using them.